# Newest version of R broke everything (ubuntu, version 3.03/version 3.10)

Tags: r

I updated R through the ubuntu software manager to 3.03.  When I run R, it shows version 3.10 beta which I DON'T want, however, there is only mention of version 3.03 in the software manager.  Furthermore, this new version of R doesn't recognize that I have installed ANY of my previously installed packages.

What the heck happened?  Why is it showing a beta version and what happened to all my packages?

Comment: We would probably have to see the command line code you used to update to tell you exactly what happened.

Comment: The lack pf packages is expected when going to 3.1.x from 3.0.x, but clearly you needed to be more specific in what you requested.

Comment: I used the ubuntu update manager to update the software.

Answer (score 2):

There is no package version for the GNU R statistical computation and graphics system more recent than r-base 3.0.1 in any supported version of Ubuntu. Therefore it looks like you have added a PPA for GNU R to your software sources, and that is why you are being offered r-base 3.10 BETA as an installation candidate.

In order to return your system to normal, remove the GNU R PPA from your software sources if you added that PPA by running a command of the form: `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:REPOSITORY-NAME`. Then tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about by running the command: `sudo apt-get update`. Search for GNU R in the Ubuntu Software Center, or install GNU R from the terminal by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

It is much preferred to install GNU R from the Ubuntu Software Center, because at the same time you install GNU R from the Ubuntu Software Center, you will be able to see a list of GNU R Add-ons to install if you scroll down to the bottom of the r-base **More Info** screen.

Comment: No version later than 3.0.1? That seems odd. We are at 3.0.3 at the moment. It's also odd to recommend using r-base. Generally people will want to use the devel version so they can compile packages. I fear you know more about Ubuntu than you do about R and may want to refer this person to more knowledgeable sources. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu/10476798#10476798

Comment: @BondedDust OK, I'll give you the link to the very latest version of r-base (version 3.0.2) from the repos, the one from Ubuntu 14.04 which is still in BETA. Here is the link: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-base&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all. I have also posted a comment to thc over at stackoverflow.com. Thanks for your help. I hope that I will be able to find out whether he wants to compile R packages so that I can sort this out.

Comment: Most linux users of R will need the devel version because the packages using C code are not generally distributed as binaries. We Mac users get binaries but often need to compile packages from sources and so need to install the proper development tools from Apple. The Debian fork of linux has good support on stackoverflow, so I'm not sure why this question was migrated.